# How can I provide an api in `meteor` server?

Tags: api, meteor

How can I provide an api in `meteor` server? What I want to do is to make a simple api:

```
POST /hostname/create-account/username
```

Then I can call the Account.createUser to create an account and then return the uid back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like [meteor router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router). There is also another package called the [collections api](https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi) but it might not be useful in this case with the user. But it would help you with other collections.

With meteor router you can create a server side route e.g

**server side js**

```
Meteor.Router.add('/hostname/create-account/username', 'POST', function() {
   //this.params contains all the POST fields
   return "OK";
});
```

Keep in mind you need to use [meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) to [access these community packages](http://atmosphere.meteor.com) (such as meteor router)